# How to install packages in oracles 11g express

Tags: oracle, express, oracle11g

I installed oracle 11g express. I need to do an audit on oracle database.

The sql command that i need to run are calling the packages

- 'UTL_DBWS'
- 'UTL_ORAMTS'
- 'UTL_HTTP'
- 'DBMS_SYS_SQL'
- 'DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE'
- 'DBMS_AQADM_SYSCALLS'
- 'DBMS_REPACT_SQL_UTL'
- 'INITJVMAUX'
- 'DBMS_STREAMS_ADM_UTL'
- 'DBMS_AQADM_SYS'
- 'DBMS_STREAMS_RPC'
- 'DBMS_AQADM_SYS'
- 'DBMS_PRVTAQIM'
- 'LTADM'
- 'WWV_DBMS_SQL'
- 'DBMS_IJOB'
- 'DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER'

None of those packages seem to exist in my installation.

Did those packages exist in oracle 11g express or do i have to install them? if yes how?

Comment: Simply you cannot in the free version. If you need them, then you must buy the version that have them.